# How to edit htaccess file to rewrite http domain to https?

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I would like to modify my `htaccess` so:

http:// domain.com/REQUEST is redirected to https:// domain.com/REQUEST

but

http:// blog.domain.com/REQUEST still goes to http:// blog.domain.com/REQUEST

and

https:// blog.domain.com/REQUEST is redirected to http:// blog.domain.com/REQUEST

how the code should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```

This is assuming main domain and sub domains are all pointed to same `DocumentRoot`.